# Capturing all matches in quantified regular expression

Tags: string, regex, string-matching

I am trying to capture repeated patterns from a string using regular expressions. More precisely, I am trying to parse LDAP schema definitions.

An example string:

```
( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.8 DESC 'Certificate' X-BINARY-TRANSFER-REQUIRED 'TRUE' X-NOT-HUMAN-READABLE 'TRUE' )
```

A regular expression (Python/extended regex) that matches the string and all relevant components is:

```
^\( (?P<oid>\d+(\.\d+)*) ((?P<keyword>[A-Z-]+) (?P<value>[^' ]+|'[^']+'|\(.+\)) )+\)$
```

I have named the relevant matching groups. The question is how I can capture all occurences of P and P? By default, only the last occurance is captured while the other ones are matched only.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat Why should I not ask on Programmers?

Comment: This question belongs on StackOverflow because it is about an implementation issue.

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) referred in prior comment? "If your code or your IDE doesn't work, ask on..." etc

Comment: Is `''` not a valid value?

Comment: @mike-samuel No, not in LDAP syntax, if I am not mistaken :)

Comment: @DominikGeorge, As far as I can tell, RFC 4523 defers to GSER per verbiage like "Values of this syntax MUST be encoded using GSER
   [RFC3641]", and all the quoted string variants in RFC 3641 allow empty strings per ABNF rules like `StringValue       = dquote *SafeUTF8Character dquote`.  There may be other controlling verbiage that explicitly disallows the empty string but I can't quickly find it, and it looks like `[^"]*` is insufficient to find the boundary of GSER strings because of variants like ` dquote dquote /       ; escaped double quote`. The string body could be `"(?:[^"]|"")*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a way if you use the [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that allows to store the results of a repeated capture group, example:

```
import regex

line = '''( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.8 DESC 'Certificate' X-BINARY-TRANSFER-REQUIRED 'TRUE' X-NOT-HUMAN-READABLE 'TRUE' )'''

pattern = r'''(?x) # switch the VERBOSE (free-spacing) mode on
^                  
\( [ ]*
(?P<oid>\d+(?:\.\d+)*) \s+  # use a non-capturing group when there is
(?:                         # no need to capture something
    (?P<keyword>[A-Z-]+) [ ]+
    (?P<value> [^' ]+ | '[^']*' | \(.+\)) [ ]*
)+
\)
$ 
'''

m = regex.match(pattern, line)
print m.capturesdict()
```

You obtain:

```
{'oid': ['1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.8'], 'keyword': ['DESC', 'X-BINARY-TRANSFER-REQUIRED', 'X-NOT-HUMAN-READABLE'], 'value': ["'Certificate'", "'TRUE'", "'TRUE'"]}
```

---

About the subpattern `\(.+\)`:

It looks like a strange way to deal nested parens (because of the greedy quantifier). But this subpattern will give the expected result if there are only one value between parens.

One more time, the new regex module allow you to reuse a subpattern (defined in a capture group), allowing to build a recursive pattern, example:

```
(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))
```

*(where `(?1)` refers to the pattern in the capture group 1 (the subpattern itself))*

So, you can rewrite the *value* subpattern like that:

```
(?P<value> [^' ]+ | '[^']*' | (\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)) )
```

Note: But if you were not trying to deal with nested parenthesis, forget that and use `\([^)]*\)`

Comment: I used `\(.+\)` as a placeholder only because I did not finish writing the pattern yet ;).